# Unreal Engine 5.3 билд для Play Market

Tags: android, google-play-console, unreal-engine-5

Установлено все как тут
https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/how-to-set-up-android-sdk-and-ndk-for-your-unreal-engine-development-environment/

При выгрузке в Гугл плей выдает ошибку - не могу понять что нужно обновить или какой файл в какой папке отредактировать

> Мы обнаружили, что как минимум в одном наборе App Bundle из этого выпуска используются следующие версии библиотеки Play Платежей:
> AIDL
> Указанные версии не поддерживаются. Чтобы опубликовать приложение, перейдите на поддерживаемую версию Play Платежей*
> https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/deprecation-faq

Эту ссылку прикладывают для помощи - но вообще не понятно в движке проблема или что-то от андроида обновить нужно

Comment: Что-то для андроида обновить нужно. А конкретно библиотеку Google Play Платежей: AIDL.
Вам нужно перейти на 5ую или лучше сразу 6ую версию

Comment: а как это сделать? Я всё по последней инструкции от разработчиков UE устанавливал, не добавляя никаких библиотек